# Voevodsky's motives and Deligne's systems of realizations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, motives, triangulated-categories, mixed-hodge-structure

$\newcommand{\gm}{\mathrm{gm}}$Let $\mathbf{DM}_{\gm}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z})$ be Voevodsky's category of geometric motives over $\mathbb{Q}$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ (e.g. as on p.124 of [Mazza-Voevodsky-Weibel's lecture notes](https://www.claymath.org/library/monographs/cmim02.pdf)). Let $\mathcal{C}$ denote the category of systems of realizations over $\mathbb{Q}$ in the sense of 1.9-1.10 of Deligne, "[le groupe fondamental de la droite moins trois points](https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/61_LeGroupeFondamentalDroite.pdf)".

The category $\mathbf{DM}_{\gm}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z})$ should be the derived category of the conjectural category $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{Q})$ of mixed motives over $\mathbb{Q}$. There should furthermore be a realization functor from this latter category to $\mathcal{C}$.

That would imply that there's a realization functor from $\mathbf{DM}_{\gm}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z})$ to the derived category of $\mathcal{C}$. Has anyone constructed such a functor?

The realization functors from $\mathbf{DM}_{\gm}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z})$ should give rise to complexes of Betti, étale, de Rham, etc. cohomology. I would furthermore hope there are comparison isomorphisms between these complexes *up to homotopy* (is this clear?). But it's not clear that you could actually get a complex of individual objects with comparison isomorphisms (M5 in 1.4 of Deligne). It seems that this might be related to lifting these isomorphisms to the chain level (which in turn relates to lifting to the level of stable $\infty$-categories of complexes rather than derived categories). This seems especially subtle in the étale-Betti comparison (maybe the pro-étale site might help?). Also, since Deligne's article was written, people realized one should include a de Rham-étale comparison, and I'm guessing a chain-level version might follow from the recent $A_{inf}$ cohomology. Finally, the Betti-de Rham comparison seems related to (maybe even follows from?) [work of Brad Drew](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.10129) on realizations of motives in mixed Hodge modules.

Comment: There is a paper Huber, Annette Realization of Voevodsky's motives. J. Algebraic Geom. 9 (2000), no. 4, 755–799.  (+ Corrigendum). Does it answer your questions?

Comment: I am not aware of any "stable $\infty$-category of chain complexes", or any *canonical* chain complexes representing étale cohomology, either. Even for Betti, I don't know what chain complex you want to choose.